# Be notified of the loading of a new data-series in Visiblox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visiblox

I have a **Visiblox chart** with a single data-series whose values are **data-bound**.

The issue is that the data source has thousands of items (key-value pairs), so update is quite sluggish.

So I wanted to display a spinner during loading:

- the chart detects new values and will trigger update
- I start the spinner
- chart loads the data
- I stop the spinner

But **how can I be notified by Visiblox when it's going to update and just after it has finished to update?**

I'd like to avoid any plumbing like:

- creating a dedicated property for storing the chart data
- detecting when the source values change
- triggering the spinner
- feeding the data into the chart synchronously
- when the chart returns stop the spinner

(not even sure it would work)

Note that maybe this is impossible if the entire UI is frozen. :(

Comment: That might be a question for Visiblox themselves, especially if you are paying for their product!

Comment: @JMK: wise advice, I'm just too addicted to SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have had any previous experience with 'spinners' as you call them, but in my opinion, you will not be able to achieve your requirements. Because WPF cannot display animating `.gif` files *without custom animation code*, this basically means that they cannot be displayed without UI thread interaction.

Now if you wanted to display a loading `.gif` while your application was performing some long running process in a background thread, that would be fine. However, even if you found an event to attach to, you want your spinner to be animated *at the same time* as the control is using the UI thread to draw the chart.

This would end with unexpected results at best and is more likely to just display a partially frozen spinner while extending the time that the control takes to draw the chart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sheridan. It's what I feared. :( I guess that with a second window with its own event-loop this would be possible but it's not worth the trouble. :)